# How to perform inner join

Tags: mysql, join

I'm new to SQL. I've two tables *agents*, *orders*. The question is as follows:

"*Display name and phone number of agents who delivered orders between 2008-08-01 and 2008-09-23 in either of cities New York, Toronto or Mumbai with orders amounting above 1000*".

**agents**

```
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| agent_code   | varchar(6)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| agent_name   | varchar(40)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| working_area | varchar(35)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| commission   | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| phone_no     | varchar(15)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| country      | varchar(25)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Sample row:

```
+------------+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+---------+
| agent_code | agent_name | working_area | commission | phone_no     | country |
+------------+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+---------+
| A001       | Subbarao   | Bangalore    |       0.14 | 077-12346674 |   N/A   |
+------------+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+---------+
```

**orders**

```
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ord_num         | decimal(6,0)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| ord_amount      | decimal(12,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| advance_amount  | decimal(12,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ord_date        | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| cust_code       | varchar(6)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| agent_code      | varchar(6)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ord_description | varchar(60)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Sample row:

```
+---------+------------+----------------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+
| ord_num | ord_amount | advance_amount | ord_date   | cust_code | agent_code | ord_description |
+---------+------------+----------------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+
|  200100 |    1000.00 |         600.00 | 2008-08-01 | c00013    | a003       | sod             |
+---------+------------+----------------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+
```

Here's is what I have tried:

`select agent_name, phone_no from agents inner join orders on agents.agent_code=orders.agent_code where working_area="New York" and ord_date>2008-08-01 and ord_date<2008-09-23 and ord_amt>800;`

But I'm getting error on joining itself. Please help me.

> ERROR: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'agents.agent_code' in 'on clause'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need single quotes around dates and varchar values

```
SELECT agents.agent_name, agents.phone_no, orders.ord_num, orders.ord_amount
FROM agents 
INNER JOIN orders 
    ON agents.agent_code = orders.agent_code 
WHERE
    rd_amt>800
    AND working_area='New York'
    AND ord_date BETWEEN '2008-08-01' AND '2008-09-23';
```

**EDIT**

A little more explanation, when writing a query you need to put single quotes `'` around `varchar` and `date` values so that they can be interpreted. additionally `BETWEEN` shorthand way to write greater than and less than
e.g.

`ord_date BETWEEN '2008-08-01' AND '2008-09-23'`

is functionally the same as

`ord_date >= '2008-08-01' AND ord_date <= '2008-09-23'`

Comment: Please explain a little bit. whats happening here.

Answer (score -2):

```
select 
    agents.agent_name, agents.phone_no 
from 
    agents, orders
where 
    agents.agent_code=orders.agent_code
    and agents.working_area="New York" 
    and orders.ord_date>2008-08-01 
    and orders.ord_date<2008-09-23 
    and orders.ord_amt>800
```

Comment: No inner join required ?

Comment: this is short hand for a `CROSS JOIN` the poster is specifically asking about an `INNER JOIN`